# Avro union - type information in resulting json

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a part of a java application that writes an AVRO encoded object into a Kafka topic. I use the `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer` to send messages into the topic. The Producer is configured to use the `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer`.

The AVRO schema contains the following field among others:

```
{
  "name": "field1",
  "type": [
    "null",
    "string"
  ],
  "default": null
}
```

Which basically means that it's a string field which can be null.

After sending an object to the topic, I inspect its content with the following terminal command:

```
./kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker-host:9091 --topic test-topic-1
  --property schema.registry.url=http://schema-host:8081 --from-beginning
```

As I result I would expect to see a JSON that has the following attribute:

```
{"field1": "something"}
```

However, in reality I see this:

```
{"field1": {"string": "something"}}
```

Along with that, if I simply use a `toString()` method on the object extending the `SpecificRecordBase` before actually sending it to the topic, I see a JSON formatted as I expect.

Is there a way to actually get the first option in the topic, without this extra type information being a part of the JSON?

Comment: Are you using the case class generated by avro to produce your message to kafka?
case class SomeSchema(var field1: Option[String]) extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase ?

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna yes, correct

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to actually get the first option in the topic, without this extra type information being a part of the JSON?

There is not for `avro-console-consumer`. It is using `GenericRecord`, not `SpecificRecord`

Since the field is a union-type the Avro Record JSON-encoded output must include the `type` of the field for that value.